# How to share code between node and react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify

I use React on server rendering, so the react code need to be used both in node and client, on client side I use browserify.

now suppose I have a component:

```
var item = React.createClass({
    //code here
})
```

in order to use this component in node I have to require React first, so the component will be

```
var React = require('React');
var item = React.createClass({
    //code here
})
```

but if I use this component in client via browserify, the React librray will be required, in this case my build js file will be too big. I know I can ignore React in browserify like

```
browserify -i React
```

but if I ignore the React then the code:

```
var React = require('React');
```

will cause an error "undefined is not a function"

any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: "the React library will be required, in this case my build js file will be too big". => You should have React library on the client side to use it on the client side. But you can just send the rendered page and not use react afterwards on the client. Is that what you want?

Comment: that is what I did,I include the react library via script tag,that is why I do not want to require it again in browse rift

Comment: no that is not what I want

Answer (score 2):

You can put your vendor packages in a separate bundle:

```
browserify -r react -r underscore > vendor.js
```

And then declare that those dependencies will be provided by an external bundle (or multiple):

```
browserify -x react -x underscore main.js > bundle.js
```

And include both in your page:

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

You don't need to rebuild the vendor bundle(s) when you build your main bundle (unless you've upgraded dependencies).  Usually you don't actually need to do this, and if you're concerned about build times in development: watchify is a a good replacement/addition.

When something is `-r`'d you can also require it in a plain script tag.  This means that there's now a require global, which may clash with other scripts on the page.

```
<script>
    var React = require('react');
</script>
```

Comment: I think this will work, but should't the  `<script src="main.js"></script>` be `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`?  and how to -r the react, I tried and it says can not find the react module.

Comment: I just tried this `if(typeof window === 'undefined'){var React=require('React')}`, this works on node but it seems browserify will strill require the React.

Comment: I just want to require React on the server and not require React on the client, is this really that hard

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do that this doesn't do.  Also it's `require('react')` (lowercase 'r', otherwise it won't work on case sensitive filesystems)

Comment: ok let me explain , say I have a A.js , this file contain an react component, in order to use this A.js in nodejs , I have to add `var React = require('React')`, right?, now If I use this A.js directly in client via browserify , this `var React = require('React')` will bundle the whole React library, I don't want that, because I already include the React library via script tag, so I need to remove `var React = require('React')` when used in client. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: See insin's answer for the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already including React via a separate `<script>` tag, use the [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) transform to rewrite your `require('react')` call to use the global `React` variable.

Add the following config to your `package.json`:

```
"browserify-shim": {
  "react": "global:React"
}
```

Use the transform when bundling:

```
browserify -t browserify-shim lib/index.js -o build/index.js
```

The bundled version should look something like this:

```
var React = (typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.React : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global.React : null);
```

Alternatively, you can omit the need for the `-t browserify-shim` argument by adding some browserify transform config to your `package.json`

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
}
```